# Why does it hold: the "observation" from Error Bounds for Exponential Operator Splittings by Jahnke & Lubich

Tags: schrodinger-operators

In the paper, Tobias Jahnke and Christian Lubich (2000), "Error bounds for exponential operator splittings." BIT Numerical Mathematics,
(Here is the link for the paper: http://www.math.kit.edu/ianm3/~jahnke/media/jahnke_lubich_2000.pdf)

I cannot see why it holds:

$\|U^n\|_{H_1}\leq (1+cn\tau) \|U^0\|_{H_1}$ and $\|U^n\|_{H_2}\leq (1+cn\tau)^2 \|U^0\|_{H_2}$.

It is on the page 742, for proving the global error of the Strang time splitting for the Schrodinger equation.

Could anyone show please? Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2):

Actually, you can choose a slightly different path and then you do not need this estimate (which is actually also not too complicated).
One possibility is that you check the Internet Seminar lecture notes, where the results of this paper were also worked out for students:

https://numerical-analysis.uibk.ac.at/isem-mathematik/index.php/Overview.html

The result is in Lecture 10, but relies on the Lax equivalence theorem from Lecture 4.

Comment: Thank you very much for your valuable comment. I went though your reference carefully. I understand that the error of the splitting is of second order. But still I do not see why $\|U^n\|_{H_1}$ can be bounded using $\|U^0\|_{H_1}$. Does it mean, they are saying the operator generates an analytic semigroup?